# Automatically copy foobar2000 playlist content to specified folder at specified times?

Tags: export, playlists, foobar2000

so Foobar is an integral part of managing my entire music collection. I have it setup to automatically boot and run as a UPNP renderer/server etc. I have BTSYNC setup to mirror my collection with my work PC so that I have all my music at work too. I also have setup a custom tag to rank tracks so that they automatically get added to a "Rotation" playlist. So I could be listening to a song at work, rank it, and have that change automatically reflect at home. Every so often, I will select all the files in this playlist and I will use the file operations/copy-to function and copy those songs to a specific dropbox folder which automatically gets downloaded to my phone and tablets.
This system works fine for me, but I was wondering whether there's an automated way to have this foobar2000 playlist files automatically "copied-to" at regular intervals.

Comment: I thought I can suggest [foo_autoplaylist_bind](http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=71569) which synchronizes a playlist to a specific folder. But at least for me it seems broken. But please try it yourself